# @angular/material barrel import cost

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using the latest Angular & CLI versions (~6.1.6), and the latest @angular/material library  (~6.4.7), I'm finding a pretty significant performance penalty when using an import from @angular/material's primary entry point (`public_api.ts`):

```
import { MatButtonModule }  from '@angular/material';
```

If I update the import statement to use the secondary endpoint:

```
import { MatButtonModule }  from '@angular/material/button';
```

My vendor bundle is reduced by ~2.6MB, and page render speed decreases by ~200ms.

With `@angular/cli`'s tree shaking abilities, the ultimate production build size is equivalent with either import statement. As a result, I feel people often favor the development semantics of the terser import statement, not realizing/understanding the dev-time performance penalty.

**Why isn't the performance penalty of 3rd party "barrel importing" discussed more? I've had a really hard time finding any documentation on the decision making process and/or performance implications of these choices.**

Comment: I just tried changing ~12 imports from the barrel to the file with no change in bundle size running material 6.4.6 (I doubt such a breaking change would be introduced in a patch bump).  Can you double check your scripts and make a public repo that produces this?

Answer (score 0):

So when you import barrel, webpack will add all exports from the barrel to your bundle.js. 
When you import a specific file like below

```
import { MatButtonModule }  from '@angular/material/button';
```

Will be imported only **button** file.

But the webpack 2 release came with built-in support for ES2015 modules (alias harmony modules) as well as unused module export detection. The new webpack 4 release expands on this capability with a way to provide hints to the compiler via the "sideEffects" package.json property to denote which files in your project are "pure" and therefore safe to prune if unused.

There are several tips to get rid of "dead code"( imports which included in your bundle but not used)

- Use ES2015 module syntax (i.e. import and export).
- Add a "sideEffects" property to your project's package.json file.
- Use [production](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#mode-production) mode configuration option to enable various optimizations including minification and [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed overview on tree shaking. As I mentioned in my original comment though - the tree shaking functionality of webpack is working well for me - regardless of the import style (barrel vs. direct), the end "production" bundle is the same size (which is a good thing).

My concern is just that - developers quickly favor the terser barrel import syntax as a "convenience", not understanding that this does have a noticeably negative effect on the development workflow (more code to bundle at dev-time, slower rebuild times, etc.).

How many developers are actually aware of this?